# Parser for multiple formats and multiple operations (design pattern available ?)

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I am currently writing a text file parser for several formats. While the text file is parsed, there are different kinds of operations to do. I am trying to do something clean using OOP.
Here is where I am stuck :

```
abstract class Parser
{
    abstract protected function DoSomeStuff($data);

    public function Parse($src)
    {
        if ( $this->GetFormat($src) == 1 )
        {                       
            $data =$this->GetSomeDataFromFormat1($src);
            DoSomeStuff($data);
        }
        if ( $this->GetFormat($src) == 2 )
        {
            $data = $this->GetSomeDataFromFormat2($src);
            DoSomeStuff($data);
        }
    }   
}

class DoSomething extends Parser
{
    protected function DoSomeStuff($data)
    {
        // Doing some stuff with data
    }
}

class DoSomethingElse extends Parser
{
    protected function DoSomeStuff($data)
    {
        // Doing some other stuff with data
    }
}

$ds = new DoSomething();
$ds->Parse(...);

$dse = new DoSomethingElse();
$dse->Parse(...);
```

As you can see : all the code for all files formats is in class Parser. 
What can I do to make this cleaner ?

Thanks
Antoine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) might help clean this up.

See also: [StackOverflow: [java] strategy pattern search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+strategy+pattern%29)

Comment: It seems that's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @Matt Ball :  One of the best suggestions. You have 199K.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good idea to follow a 1-class-per-file rule.

Other than that, there isn't a whole lot more you can do to clean it up.

The only other thing to decide on is how you want to load each class file, which can be done several ways.  I'd suggest making a factory class with a registry.

Comment: Agreed re: the 1-class-per-file rule.

Comment: See Matt Ball answer : Strategy Pattern base can make my code cleaner and more OOP. Applying this pattern make one class per format, and one class per "operation". A global class make the "glue" between formats and operations (I want to this with that).

Answer (score 0):

GetFormat returns and int this is not easy for a user to understand what int is what it would be best if you returned some thing like "CSV" or "XML"

Another is

```
if ( $this->GetFormat($src) == 1 )
{
}
if ( $this->GetFormat($src) == 2 )
{
}

//This should be a switch
$src = $this->getFormat($src);

switch($src){
    case 1:

    break;
    case 2:

    break;
}
```

This then prevents the code from loading a method twice when it can do it once, and a switch is less memory than an if

and the last i can spot is

GetSomeDataFromFormat1 and GetSomeDataFromFormat2

This might be to the code you have given us but an Abstract class should only ever call other Abstract methods or methods that are provided inside that class they should require the user to know they have to add 2 method's other than i like your code it's easy to read which is the main thing in coding

Comment: Thank you for your comment... But what you have commented is not my problem :-) In fact, I would like avoid totally the part with : if ( getformat()==xx) { } and I would like to avoid it by using an object way

Comment: well thats the only code that could be commented on :p, what did you want us to review?

Comment: Sorry you're right, I forgot to tell that I had a problem with the design, not the code itself (quickly written as pseudo-code).